# Unable to upload build to App Store Xcode 13.2. Invalid Bundle Structure

Tags: ios, xcode, archive, xcode13, xcode13.2

I am trying to upload build on AppStore using Xcode 13. But when I try to do so, I am getting the below error

> Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'MyApp.app/Frameworks/HHUnitConverter.framework/HHUnitConverter' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure.

When I archive the build and make it ready for upload, this is how my framework looks which is not correct I suppose[image]

And when I click on upload, after sometime I am getting this error.
[image]

I have tried deleting and reinstalling the pods, restarting Xcode and the system, clearing derived data, but nothing works.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Add "HHUnitConverter" as source file to project. instead adding as pod.

Comment: But all other frameworks which are showing in black will also give the same issue. Not sure if that's the right approach

Answer (score -1):

I recently ran into the same issue

To resolve this issue you need to select your archive, right click it, select "show in finder" then right click on the archive and select "show package contents" then select products > Applications then right click on your app and again select "Show package contents". Now find "Frameworks" folder and delete the executable file with the folder name specified in the error.

This worked for me